# ECL provider for Fredhopper is not working

Tags: ecl, fredhopper

I have prepared the FredhopperECL connection provider code and deployed the dll into the different environments. That code is running fine in the lower environment but When I am trying to fetch the data from Fredhopper using the same dll in higher environment, I am getting the below error -

Server stack trace: at com.jio.ECL.FredhopperECLProvider.FredhopperContext.GetItem(IEclUri eclUri) in N:\jio-custom\ECL\FredhoperECLProvider\FredhoperECLProvider\FredhopperContext.cs:line 93 at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContextViewToContractAddInAdapter.GetItem(IEclUriContract eclUri) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.Contracts.IContentLibraryContextContract.GetItem(IEclUriContract eclUri) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContextContractToViewHostAdapter.GetItem(IEclUri eclUri) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.Extensions.ContentLibraryContextExtensions.FindItemWithFallback(IContentLibraryContext context, IEclUri uri, MountPoint mountPoint) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.FindItem(String eclUri) at SyncInvokeFindItem(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

**UPDATE**

*This is the code where it is giving some error*

```
public IContentLibraryItem GetItem(IEclUri eclUri) // Reading one item 
{ if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "prd") 
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = new FredhopperWebService("product", eclUri.ItemId).XmlDoc(); 
        return new FredhopperProduct(eclUri.PublicationId, xmlDoc.Root.Element("product")); 
    }

    if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "pln")
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = new FredhopperWebService("plan", eclUri.ItemId).XmlDoc();
        return new FredhopperPlan(eclUri.PublicationId, xmlDoc.Root.Element("plan"));
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException();

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can share some of your code, and what is happening at line #93

Comment: Can you share any of the configuration files / the method of testing you're using?

Comment: This is clearly not related to SmartTarget, so I removed that tag.

Comment: The ECL log file probably contain additional exception details. It appears only the stack trace is included here, not the actual exception message - I would expect that to be in the log file. Given the exception text and knowing what is on line 93 it might be possible to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the help. The issue is resolved now. The problem in my case was missing proxy settings in the CMS server.After adding that settings the connector started working without any issues.