# ECL error: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id

Tags: web8.5, ecl, adobe

We are using Web 8.5 and begun development on an ECL provider for AEM.  After adding mount points to the ECL config file, error seen is:

> 2020-03-05 09:46:06,348 [100] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process request for command 'GetList' id='ecl:4-aem-root-mp-mountpoint' 2020-03-05 09:46:06,410 [100] ERROR UI.Model - System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id aem.

```
Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at 
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: at 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable 1 basedOnSchema) at
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns) at 
Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns) at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

> 2020-03-05 09:46:30,051 [126] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id='' ... System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Unable to connect to the remote server

Other details:
- The AEM server is within the corporate network, so although there is a proxy this should not be an issue.

- No helpful log events are seen when browsing the Windows event logs, a Fiddler trace of the CME GUI, or doing a CM trace while reproducing issue.  Process Monitor was used to check for ECL related errors, none were found.
- We've raised a ticket with SDL Support, and gone through some debugging sessions, but do not have any insight as to what the problem is.  SDL Support have said that there does not appear to be a user permissions issue.
- When debugging the ECL provider in Visual Studio, we've noticed that XXX.  So we are not sure if the the provider was actually deployed correctly.
- We've seen several blog posts and Tridion Stackexchange posts which discuss what seems to be similar or the same error message.  Not sure where the problem is though.

  - https://vikaskumarblogs.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/creating-sdl-tridionweb-ecl-provider-for-aws-s3-bucket/
  - [Failed initializing the External Content Library with id clp](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/failed-initializing-the-external-content-library-with-id-clp)
  - [ECL provider for Fredhopper is not working](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/ecl-provider-for-fredhopper-is-not-working)

If someone would like to see the ECL code, it can be sent directly.  Any comments would be welcome.

#

4/20/2020: this is what was captured in the tcm trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryViewToContractAddInAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServicesContract hostServices)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContractToViewHostAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServices hostServices)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(MountPointConfiguration config)
08:55:41.064 <16284> TcmServiceHost: MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint() exit. Duration: 477 ms. Returned value: ''
08:55:41.065 <16284> Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', errorCode: 0, category: General, component: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel

Server stack trace: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryViewToContractAddInAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServicesContract hostServices)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContractToViewHostAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServices hostServices)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(MountPointConfiguration config)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.<>c.<GetConfiguredMediaManagers>b__12_0(MountPointConfiguration mountPointConfiguration)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Tridion.Logging.Tracer.ConvertEnumerableToString(IEnumerable param, Int32 resultLimit)
   at Tridion.Logging.Tracer.ConvertParameterToString(Object param)
   at Tridion.Logging.TracerAttribute.OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetConfiguredMediaManagers()
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.<>c.<GetDisplayTypes>b__13_0(String s)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetDisplayTypes()
08:55:41.065 <16284> TcmServiceHost: MountPoint.GetDisplayTypes() exit. Duration: 479 ms. Returned value: ''
08:55:41.065 <16284> Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', errorCode: 0, category: General, component: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service
```

#

Retest on 04/21/2020 after review of variables for null refences, this is what the tcm trace log contained:

08:36:59.819 <32>                     TcmServiceHost: Provider.InstantiateInAppDomain(aem: AEMAssets) entry.(in : line 24)
08:36:59.829 <3300>                    Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', errorCode: 0, category: General, component: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel

Server stack trace: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.AddInSideAdapters.ContentLibraryViewToContractAddInAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServicesContract hostServices)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.AddInPipeline.V2.HostSideAdapters.ContentLibraryContractToViewHostAdapter.Initialize(String mountPointId, String configurationXmlElement, IHostServices hostServices)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint(MountPointConfiguration config)
08:36:59.829 <3300>                 TcmServiceHost: MountPoint.GetContentLibraryForMountPoint() exit. Duration: 240 ms. Returned value: ''
08:36:59.830 <3300>                  Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', errorCode: 0, category: General, component: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel

...

08:37:10.874 <3300>                     TcmServiceHost: ExternalContentLibraryConfiguration.get_Theme() exit. Duration: 0 ms. Returned value: ''
08:37:10.874 <3300>                   TcmServiceHost: HostServices..ctor() exit. Duration: 0 ms. Returned value: ''
08:37:10.950 <4008>         TcmPublisher: TransportEngine.GetDeploymentFeedback() entry.(in : line 162)
08:37:10.983 <3300>                    Error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', errorCode: 0, category: General, component: Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel

Comment: You say "when debugging in VS, we've noticed that XXX". Please post what XXX is :). Also, see the following, although somewhat dated, it has valuable information and also you have the source code for a working ecl provider which might help you in troubleshooting. https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7

Comment: Sorry about that... We initially had the issue with Symbols missing after 'attached to the process' where the process was the Tcm Service Host, but got past that and now show  Symbols loaded for our .dll.  Ultimately, we are still getting notified in the UI about the "unable to get list of items...",

Comment: Also thank you, watched that entire video on the docs.sdl site.  We matched it and can't see what else could be missing.

Comment: Welcome, Kira. Have you been able to get a basic "stubbed out" ECL setup working where get lists returns some minimum or even fake data? I understand the hesitancy to share the code, but narrowing down the issue to a few specific lines after confirming installation, setup, and configuration could help people answer pinpoint the issue (and others who follow your post later!). Cheers!

Comment: we were able to create the stub folder/stub schema and mount point was created in every publication fine, but then we introduced the .dll with the iContentLibrary implementation - at that point we starting seeing errors, which are the errors shown from the traces/logs above.

Comment: It seems this error is simply caused by a "Null reference excretion" that happens in "Initialize" method of AEM provider. (in AEM implementation of IContentLibrary.Initialize to be precise)

Comment: Thanks for replying. We reviewed for null reference in initialize function and corrected everything possible but we still can't get past this.
There errors in the logs appear to be the same. We are seeing errors in multiple places. Above I pasted the errors from our trace where it start "retested on 04/21/2020"

Comment: If you would like to see our code, we are happy to share it privately.

Comment: As Alvin has mentioned, try and troubleshoot your ecl provider in 2 parts. Do a stubbed version which returns dummy data (single item and list of items), that way you ensure that the configuration and generic setup is OK. If and when that is all working as expected, you can then try and connect your external system. Again go bit by bit leaving the the rest as stubbed. This approach will help you identify where and what the issue is exactly.